# Mail function issue

Tags: php, email

I am using mail function as i want to send message in a format for that i have used '\n' but it is showing as \n , the text does not comes in the second line.

My code is :

```
$to  = 'user@mydomain.in'; 
$from='admin@mydomain.in';
$sendername='user';
$replyto='admin@mydomain.in';
$subject='Enrollment in Course';
$message='Please enroll '.$enrolmentdetails[0][email].' in Coursefor '.$enrolmentdetails[0][productname].'.';
$message.='\nOther Details are:\nFirstname : '.$enrolmentdetails[0][cf_549].'\nLastname : '.$enrolmentdetails[0][lastname].'\nMobile No : '.$enrolmentdetails[0][cf_591];
if(sendEMail($to, $from, $sendername, $replyto, $subject, $message))
showMessage('Email with student details sent successfully.', 'main-content', 'divMsg', APP_URL."views/completeenrollments.php", 3000, 'success');
else
showMessage('There was some problem sending student details. Please try again later', 'main-content', 'divMsg', APP_URL."views/completeenrollments.php", 3000, 'error');
```

Right now i am getting this :

Please enroll newuser@gmail.com  in Course for FP - LVC Plus.\nOther Details are:\nFirstname : new \nLastname : user\nMobile No : 121213313

Please help me on this

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the newline character (or any special character), you have to enclose the string into double-quotes `"`.
E.g.

```
$message.="\nOther Details are:\nFirstname : ".$enrolmentdetails[0][cf_549]."\nLastname : ".$enrolmentdetails[0][lastname]."\nMobile No : ".$enrolmentdetails[0][cf_591];
```

---

Read about [**single quoted**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) and [**double quoted strings**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) in PHP.

From the documentation about *single quoted* strings:

> **Note:**  Unlike the three other syntaxes, variables and **escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded** when they occur in single quoted strings.

Comment: thanks felix changing single quote to double quote resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

That is because when using ' there is no interpretation of special characters like \n.
Use " instead.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use double quotes: `"\n"`